# how to re-sizing pdf content with iTextsharp

Tags: c#-4.0, pdf, itext

I just need to resize page content in a pdf file, it's not related to Reducing file size I just need to reduce each page content which is one image to be able to print it as a booklet in landscape mode.
So I need to reduce the height and the width of each page content.

I'm using iTextSharp with c#

Comment: The mechanisms of pdf viewers to scale down pdfs do not suffice?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way might be to change the size of default user space units for the pages in question.

The default user space units can be configured on a per-page basisusing the page dictionary entry **/UserUnit**, cf. table 30 in the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> **UserUnit** number *(Optional; PDF 1.6)* A positive number that shall give the size of default user space units, in multiples of 1⁄72 inch.
>   The range of supported values shall be implementation-dependent.
>
> Default value: 1.0 (user space unit is 1⁄72 inch).

Thus, all you have to do is create a PdfStamper for a PdfReader for your PDF file, iterate over the page dictionaries, read their current **/UserUnit** value (default: 1.0), reduce it as desired, write it back, mark the page dictionary as changed, and write the result of the PdfStamper.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your content to the document and set the documents pages to landscape using the SetPageSize property.
Here is the code to set the pages to Landscape:
        Document document = new Document();
        **document.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());**
        //Add some content
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Some test text"));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
        table.AddCell(cell);